# Way to make my window fits every screen size automatically

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I work on a python application using tkinter and i have a problem that after i turned it exe file and runned it on another laptop i found that because the other laptop has a smaller screen the file window isn't fitting the screen so i was hoping if there's a way that makes it fits on every screen no matter what's its size ?

i tried using PySimpleGUI with the method
`window.get_screen_size()`
`screen_size = sg.Window.get_screen_size()`
self.root.geometry(f"{screen_size[0]}x{screen_size[1]}")
but it's not effective as i don't need the full screen size in every page as my application has several pages

Comment: You should post a minimally reproducible example, otherwise we won't be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using PySimpleGui, you can use Tkinter. When you set the geometry of your window at the start of your code, use this instead:

```
screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()

root.geometry(f'{screen_width}x{screen_height}')
```

`winfo_screenwidth()` and `winfo_screenheight()` will each get the width and height or your ****main** screen**. Then set your window geometry to that size.

If you want to get the screen size of multiple windows, you can use [PyAutoGui](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).